# Mixed ANOVA different results in R vs. Matlab

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, matlab, anova

I´m trying to sort things out on the evaluation of the following data, as I have contradictory results in R vs. Matlab. I´m new to R and data evaluation ;-) and I hope I will provide enogh information to answer the question.

Background:
The design for the experiment was a 2x3 factorial (IV1 = low;high, IV2 = low;mid;high). Subjects were randomly assigned to IV2 and had to evaluate IV1 in both conditions. So I thought of it as a repeated measure, a within factor in an ANOVA design. IV1 was randomly assigned to the position within the experiment. I thought of IV2 as the between factor in the design. The DV was a measured on a 5-point lickert scale.

The data basically looks like as follows:

```
     x <- Dat       

    str(Dat)
    'data.frame':   3958 obs. of  4 variables:
    $ Id_new : Factor w/ 93 levels "2","3","4","5",..: 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 ...
        $ within : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...
    $ between: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
        $ DV     : num  1 2 3 1 0 4 2 0 3 2 ...

     head(Dat)
     Id_new within between DV
        2      2       3    1
        2      1       3    2
        3      2       3    3
        3      1       3    1
        4      1       3    0
        4      2       3    4
```

At first I ran an ANOVA

```
    aov(DV ~ between * within + Error((Id_new)/within), data = (x))
```

which returned the following results:

```
    Error: Id_new
              Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
    between    2  20.64  10.318   5.494 0.00561 **
    Residuals 90 169.04   1.878                   

    Error: Id_new:within
                   Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
    within          1  92.48   92.48   72.84 3.19e-13 ***
    between:within  2   1.19    0.60    0.47    0.626    
    Residuals      90 114.26    1.27                     

    Error: Within
                     Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
    between           2     54   27.11   15.41 2.17e-07 ***
    between:within    2     76   38.21   21.72 4.18e-10 ***
    Residuals      3768   6629    1.76                     

    n in IV(1,1) / IV (2,1) = 662
    n in IV(1,1) / IV (2,2) = 658
    n in IV(1,1) / IV (2,3) = 699
    for IV2 ist the same. So data is balanced for "within" but not for "between".
    N = 3958
```

but because I was unsure whether I did the ANOVA the right way, i aksed for someone to do the ANOVA. But his results showed way bigger F-values: 66.x (p = 7.xe-16) for "within" and 28.x (p = 8.xe-13) for "between".
Unforntunately this person doesn´t know R so we couln´t figure out the problem.

Furthermore, beacuse of imbalance in the between grops factor I tried:

```
     e <- lme(DV ~ between * within, data = (x), random = ~1|Id_new/within)
     anova(e)
                    numDF denDF   F-value p-value
     (Intercept)        1  3768 10175.364  <.0001
     between            2  3768    17.927  <.0001
     within             1    92    52.772  <.0001
     between:within     2  3768    21.932  <.0001
```

and again I get different F-values...especially for "within"
So I am not shure if what Im doing here is anyhow correct. With the use of aov() in the first place and switching to lme()...

Do I handle the data the wrong way?

Is data in long format not appropriate for the use in aov(), lme() or

do I need some more ordering for the data?

I also do not understand yet why DFs of residuals are varying...

Thank you very much for your interest and time in advance!